# Why isn't the [] operator const for STL maps?

Tags: c++, constants

Contrived example, for the sake of the question:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction( int x ) const
{
  std::cout << m_map[x] << std::endl
}
```

This won't compile, since the [] operator is non-const.

This is unfortunate, since the [] syntax looks very clean.  Instead, I have to do something like this:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction( int x ) const
{
  MyMap iter = m_map.find(x);
  std::cout << iter->second << std::endl
}
```

This has always bugged me.  Why is the [] operator non-const?

Comment: What should `operator[]` yield in case the given element does not exist?

Comment: @Frerich Raabe : The same thing as the at member function : throw std::out_of_range

Answer (score 101, accepted):

For `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, `operator[]` will insert the index value into the container if it didn't previously exist.  It's a little unintuitive, but that's the way it is.

Since it must be allowed to fail and insert a default value, the operator can't be used on a `const` instance of the container.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: `std::set` doesn't have `operator[]`.

Comment: That is the right answer, but a const version could do the same thing as the "at" member. That is throw an std::out_of_range...

Comment: When used to read a value there is no default value to provide. `std::vector` has a read operator `[]` that is `const`. `map` should do the same.

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu the convention across all containers is that `at` may throw and `[]` does not. I don't think it worth breaking that convention.

Answer (score 64):

Now that with C++11 you can have a cleaner version by using [at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/)

```
void MyClass::MyFunction( int x ) const
{
  std::cout << m_map.at(x) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If `map` have const and non-const `at()`s - why not the same also for `operator[]` ? with the const version not inserting anything but rather throwing? (Or returning an optional, when std::optional makes it into the standard)

Comment: @einpoklum The point of const correctness is mostly static compile-time checking. I'd rather the compiler complain than throw an exception because I didn't use const objects correctly.

Comment: @einpoklum Very late, but for other readers: having two overloads doing such different things would be terrible. The only reason `at` comes in two flavors is because it does a `return *this;`, and the only difference between the overloads is the `const`-ness of the reference returned. The actual effects of both `at`s are the exact same (that is, no effect).

Answer (score 30):

Note for new readers.
The original question was about STL containers (not specifically about the std::map)

It should be noted there is a const version of operator [] on most containers.
It is just that std::map and std::set do not have a const version and this is a result of the underlying structure that implements them.

From std::vector

```
reference       operator[](size_type n) 
const_reference operator[](size_type n) const
```

Also for your second example you should check for a failure to find the element.

```
void MyClass::MyFunction( int x ) const
{
    MyMap iter = m_map.find(x);
    if (iter != m_map.end())
    {
        std::cout << iter->second << std::endl
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::set` does not have `operator[]` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since operator[] might insert a new element into the container, it can't possibly be a const member function. Note that the definition of operator[] is extremely simple: m[k] is equivalent to (*((m.insert(value_type(k, data_type()))).first)).second. Strictly speaking, this member function is unnecessary: it exists only for convenience

Answer (score 0):

An index operator should only be const for a read-only container (which doesn't really exist in STL per se).

Index operators aren't only used to look at values.

Comment: The question is, why doesn't it have two overloaded versions - one `const`, another non-`const` - as e.g. `std::vector` does.

Answer (score -2):

If you declare your std::map member variable to be mutable

```
mutable std::map<...> m_map;
```

you can use the non-const member functions of std::map within your const member functions.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, though.

Comment: The API for your class lies if you do that.  The function claims that it's const -- meaning that it won't modify any member variables -- but in reality it might be modifying the m_map data member.

Comment: `mutable` can be used for members like `std::mutex`, caches and debug helpers. If the map is to be used as a cache to speed up a very expensive `const` "getter" function, then `mutable` is acceptable. You need to be careful, but it is not a terrible idea on its own.